# Register HttpHandler for a specific area in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to register an HTTP handler for a specific area only. So not as having to register it in the root web.config.

If I register the handler in the root web.config it works fine:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="/Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=6.2.12.1017, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" validate="true" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

But in the web.config inside of an area i.e areas\reporting\views\web.config
it doesn't seem to register the handler. I get the following exception:

> The http handler needed by the Report Viewer has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the configuration file.

Any advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is one that plagues many of us: that the Area configs are not part of the inheritance tree of configuration within the project. They serve simply to configure the views and delivery of therein.

An option for you would be to create a wrapper class that inherits from that handler, register it globally and invoke the functionality of it only when you spot the area in the current context's routeData.

I hope this helps in some way. It's certainly pain that I have felt myself over the years.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was something along those lines. It's not crucial in this instance that I isolate the handler to that area but that's a clever solution. Thanks :)